# Check if an Excel object exists in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel

What is a good way to check if an Excel object exists in VB.NET?

I know that in VBA I could write something like:

```
Sub TestifTableExists(name) as boolean
    dim exists as range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set exists = ActiveSheet.listobject(name).range
    On Error Goto 0
    if exists is nothing
        TestifTableExists= false
    else
        TestifTableExists= true
    end if
end sub
```

But now I'm now transitioning to VB.NET and thought maybe there is a better way to do it in VB.NET.

Comment: VB.NET or VBA?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: I know how to do the above in VBA. I think the normal practices are to either use On Error Resume Next together with On Error Goto 0 or to loop all objects looking for a certain object. But I am transitionining into VB.NET and don't know what the best practice is in VB.NET. So in my qyestion I am looking for a VB.NET solution?

Comment: Ok.  That makes sense.  It's just confusing because your question starts by asking "*What is a good way to check if an Excel object exists **in VBA**?*"

Comment: I'm sorry about that. That was a mistake by me.

Comment: No problem.  I'm just happy to see someone who's transitioning from VBA to VB.NET that wants to do it right :)  +1  Unfortunately I don't have experience with interfacing with Excel, so I'm not sure if there is any easier way.  I suspect there isn't, since you are still accessing the same COM object, so it still has the same functionality.  However, even so, you should use a `Try/Catch` block in VB.NET rather than `On Error`.

Comment: There's an Office namespace you import - I think it's Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop - that exposes the Excel API. It's pretty freaking powerful. .NET 2 had a separate download called Visual Studio Tools for Office, which had even more power, but I don't know if it's included with the current versions of the framework or not.

Comment: Thank you Tim! I'm using the intertop as well as VSTO

Answer (score 0):

There is a ListObjects function in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

```
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileNameWithPath)
    ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    ws.ListObjects(Index As Object)
```